# Combobox has no value in if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to display a Msgbox when the user doesn't enter any value in Combobox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MonthCases (ComboBox1.Value)
Unload Me
End Sub
```

MonthCases are in a separate module `MonthCases(X As Integer)` with multiple `If` statements for `x`.

Comment: why not checking the value of the combobox, before calling MonthCases  if combobox1.Value '"" then msgbox()

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. I was trying with isnull, is nothing, is empry and all of them errored out.